# Many dhclient processes running?

Tags: 12.10, dhcp, dhclient

Is it OK to have many dhclient processes running? Or is this an error and you should always have one such a process? What does it mean? Why is it listening? Is this computer a DHCP client or is it a DHCP server waiting for requests from DHCP clients?

```
netstat -nlpl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.3:25          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4929/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1284/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4929/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1388/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1098/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      969/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 :::7676                 :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::41474                :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::45221                :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::52009                :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8686                 :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::4848                 :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::3700                 :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::8181                 :::*                    LISTEN      3733/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1098/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      969/cupsd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22242           0.0.0.0:*                           1388/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14156           0.0.0.0:*                           1388/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22435           0.0.0.0:*                           **1036/dhclient**   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7146            0.0.0.0:*                           1388/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           1388/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           **6833/dhclient**   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           **1036/dhclient**   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45662           0.0.0.0:*                           957/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           957/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:29971           0.0.0.0:*                           **6833/dhclient**   
udp6       0      0 :::43897                :::*                                957/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::16303                :::*                                **6833/dhclient**   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                957/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::29968                :::*                                **1036/dhclient**   
raw    17600      0 0.0.0.0:1               0.0.0.0:*               7           6365/ping       
raw    26816      0 0.0.0.0:1               0.0.0.0:*               7           6364/ping       
raw    29120      0 0.0.0.0:1               0.0.0.0:*               7           6356/ping       
raw    35264      0 0.0.0.0:1               0.0.0.0:*               7           6270/ping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ok. I have the same problem on 2 computer:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21894/vino-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5800                 :::*                    LISTEN      21894/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      21894/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56061           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58597           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::41263                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::11978                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                -
```

In my case I used `kill 21894` (in your case, you can use `kill 3733` for example) and after netstat became like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56061           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58597           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::41263                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::11978                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                -
```

These processes were probably called from something that runs regularly like `vino-server` (in my case) or `java` (in your case) on your system.

The command `netstat -nlp` just simply lists your ports you have daemons listening on.

Comment: thank you. and why is this? what is the reason? can you suggest something?

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain It is normal - I edited my answer

Comment: but why these processes not die when their caller die?

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain Maybe because they have their  own ID